# How to search a subfolder, which doesn't exist yet, with wildcard in Python

Tags: python, wildcard, subdirectory

I'm trying to download some web pages through [pywebcopy](https://pypi.org/project/pywebcopy/). I use this library as it clones exactly same, however, it tries to download every file from the web page. As a result, sometimes it gets stuck at some file and goes to infinite loop, I guess. (I never waited more than 10 minutes.) In fact, it downloads what I want to download, which is the complete web page. So, I want to terminate its process when the file is once downloaded and go for the other web pages in a loop.

I would do it with `while` but the folder structure is too nested. And as the folder doesn't exist before library downloads them, I  couldn't make a search with `os.path`.

The folder structure is like this:

```
main_folder├───subfolder1───some_folder1  
│                 └───some_folder2
│                        some_image.png
│   
│
└───subfolder2
    └───sub_subfolder1
        └───sub_subfolder2
            └───sub_subfolder3
                └───sub_subfolder4
                    └───sub_subfolder5
                        │   index.html
                        │   some.pwc
                        │
                        └───amp
                                the_file_I_want.pwc
```

The file I need is always in amp folder. So, basically I should find that folder and check if the file is there. However the names of sub_subfolder3, sub_subfolder4 and sub_subfolder5 changes for each web page. I have to search with wildcard which is something like: "main_folder/subfolder2/**/amp/*.pwc". But the folder doesn't exist before downloading start.

what I want to do is something like this:

```
from pywebcopy import save_webpage
import glob
...

pattern = 'main_folder/subfolder2/**/amp/*.pwc'
while glob.glob(pattern).is_file() = False:
    save_webpage(url, download_folder, **kwargs)
```

It's an invalid syntax but this is what exactly I want. I've searched but couldn't come up with any solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `=` is assignment in python, not `:`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Edited.@mousetail

Comment: `glob` returns a list, not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while any(os.path.isfile(i) for i in glob.iglob(pattern)):
```

Comment: Your solution seemed correct to me but the code kept running after the file was downloaded. So maybe I should post another question to see how to terminate it when the file is downloaded. 

And also something weird happened, glob coulnd't find the file when I use "'main_folder/subfolder2/**/amp/*.pwc'' pattern. I later tried many options, among them only "/main_folder/**/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*" could find the file (As the file is the deepest one, this was lucky). Even when I set as "/main_folder/**/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*.pwc" couldn't find the file. I didn't get at all.

Comment: I tried to download http://example.com/ , but it still hanged at some part. Then I ran at command prompt and it worked. But it still hangs for the more complicated websites. Then I checked the github page of the library (https://github.com/rajatomar788/pywebcopy/issues/46)  and saw that it's a common problem. Your answer solved some part of problem, that's why I'll accept your answer.